# how to reverse url in django template syntax

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

for example, I can  reverse a url in this way:

```
{% url 'home:index' %}
```

but if I need to compare a url in a `if` sentence, like this:

```
{% if request.path == url %}
```

and I want to replace the url with a reverse one 
but I can't do this:

```
{% if request.path == {% url 'home:index' %} %}
```

So is there another way can solve this?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: can you explain the *use-case*?

Comment: You better split your template and use only parts a view needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url tag takes an argument `as <var>` that saves the result of the reverse to a variable. You can then use this variable in your comparison

```
{% url 'home:index' as home_url %}
{% if request.path == home_url %}
```